# My javascript only call my webservice if I set a breakpoint.Do you know why?

Tags: c#, javascript, json

Could you explain me why my javascript code call my webservice only when I set a beakpoint on the line ].getJSON but not if I remove the breakpoint?

```
$(function () {
            $("#" + @Model.BidObjectId).submit(function () {
                 alert("Test");
                 $.getJSON("http://localhost:11523/Service1.svc/GetBidObject?id=@Model.BidObjectId", function (data) {
                    alert(data)
                });
            });
        });
```

The test alert is always showed but the breakpoint in my svc file is never reached except I put a javascript breakpoint in chrome on the line ].getJSON...

Here is the code in my webservice

```
public List<BidObject> GetBidObject(string id)
        {
            List<BidObject> list = new List<BidObject>();
            list.Add(new BidObject() { BidObjectId = 1, Title = "Name" + id, Date = DateTime.Now });
            return list;
        }

[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetBidObject?id={id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        List<BidObject> GetBidObject(string id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it

I just added a return false in the javascript. But why I don't know.

```
$(function () {
            $("#" + @Model.BidObjectId).submit(function () {
                 alert("Test");
                 $.getJSON("http://localhost:11523/Service1.svc/GetBidObject?id=@Model.BidObjectId", function (data) {
                    alert(data)
                });
                return false; // Prevent browser to submit
            });


        });
```

Comment: From what you say in your comment it looks like you had this hooked up to a links on click event in which case when your browser "vists '#'" it was causing a page reload interrupting your JSON call.

Answer (score 0):

Mayb this helps out
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/